# Getting the value of a particular key from a dictionary inside nested list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

So I'm trying to parse the **SSL.cert.issuer** & **SSL.cert.subject** fields from a dictionary inside a list, which is inside a dictionary. I tried using .item() & .get(). The get works for the key on the outside, but if I try to get() the value of something in a nested data field, it fails.

Sample dict:

```
{u'area_code': None,
 u'asn': u'',
 u'city': u'',
 u'country_code': u'RU',
 u'country_code3': None,
 u'country_name': u'Russian Federation',
 u'data': [{u'_id': u'XX',
            u'_shodan': {},
            u'asn': u'XX',
            u'cpe': [],
            u'cpe23': [],
            u'data': u'',
            u'domains': [u'XX'],
            u'hash': ,
            u'hostnames': [u'XX'],
            u'http': {},
            u'ip': XX,
            u'ip_str': u'XX',
            u'isp': u'XX',
            u'location': {},
            u'opts': {},
            u'ssl': {u'acceptable_cas': [],
                     u'alpn': [u'h2', u'http/1.1'],
                     u'cert': {u'expired': False,
                               u'expires': u'XX',
                               u'extensions': [{},{}],
                               u'fingerprint': {},
                               u'issued': u'XX',
                               u'issuer': {u'C': u'US',
                                           u'CN': u'R3',
                                           u'O': u"Let's Encrypt"},
                               u'subject': {u'CN': u'XX'},
                               u'version': 2},
```

Can someone please help me with a pythonic way to get the data.SSL.cert.issuer & data.SSL.cert.subject fields from the above dict.

Comment: Of course it would fail, `.get` is a dict method, not a list method. If you have a list you either need to access a dict directly using an index, or iterate all the dicts in the list with a `for` loop

Comment: Why not show *how* you are trying to use `.get()` instead of merely saying that it isn't working? Properly used, you should be able to use it to get what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you want from the dict you have shown us, do this:

```
>>> a={u'area_code': None, ...etc...,
>>> print(a['data'][0]['ssl']['cert']['issuer'])
{'C': 'US', 'CN': 'R3', 'O': "Let's Encrypt"}
```

If there is more than one element in the list `a` then you will need something like:

```
>>> for x in a['data']: 
        print(x['ssl']['cert']['issuer'])
```

which will get all of the certificate issuers in the data.

As a side note, it appears you are using Python 2 (because Python 3 recognizes but ignores the string prefix `u`). If that is so, please bear in mind that as a beginner you should *not* be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of use who still work with it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code.